# How to put an if inside an if statement in initState in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to put an if statement inside another if inside an insitstate in flutter app as I did it but It did't do what it is supposed to do like if the initstate focused on being a function instead of being an initstate here is my code :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((res) {
      print(res);
      if (res != null) {
        if (userType == 'Student') {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/StudentsPage');
        } else if (userType == 'Teacher') {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/TeacherPage');
        } else if (userType == 'Admin') {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/AdminPage');
        }
      } else {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Error"),
                content: Text('Error In Validating Your Account.'),
                actions: [
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Ok"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
      }
    });
  }
```

It is supposed to get the firebase user which it did but It doesn't do auto login when I do restart which it happens by deleting the second if and only doing one Navigation without controlling it, So any Ideas what is the proplem, because I reached a dead end XD.

Where I assign a val to userType 'Which is working as I printed Its val':

```
void getUserData() async {
    try {
      firestoreInstance
          .collection('Users')
          .document(usernameController.text)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          email = (value.data)['email'];
          password = (value.data)['password'];
          gender = (value.data)['gender'];
          username = (value.data)['username'];
          userType = (value.data)['userType'];
        });
        print('$userType');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where do you set the ```userType``` ?

Comment: Notice that you cant use context inside initState, the dialog will throw you an error. 
Put your showDialog inside WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_) {//showDialog});

Comment: first I set my userType down and it is not null I printed it and give me a val.

Comment: second I can put conext inside an initState and It worked just fine as I hoped